# Why in the Jensen's formula the number of zeros in the disc $|z|<R$ is finite?

Tags: general-topology, complex-analysis, complex-numbers

> If $f(z)$ is analytic inside and on the circle $|z| = R$ except for zeros $a_1, a_2, ..., a_m$ of multiplicities $p_1, p_2, ... p_m$ in $|z|<R$ and if $f(0)\neq 0$, then Jensen's formula gives
> $$\frac{1}{2 \pi }\int_0^{2\pi} \ln |f(Re^{i\theta})|d\theta = \ln |f(0)| + \sum_{k=1}^{m}p_k \ln \left( \frac{R}{|a_k|}\right)$$

**Question** Why in the Jensen's formula the number of zeros in the disc $|z|<R$ is finite?

Attempt: Since $f$ is Holomorphic on $|z|\leq R$ which is a compact set and hence the number of zeros of $f$ must be finite. See- [The set of zeros of a holomorphic function is finite in compact sets](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/855019/the-set-of-zeros-of-a-holomorphic-function-is-finite-in-compact-sets)

Comment: You are right. $f$ is analytic in some open set which includes the closes unit disk and zeros are isloated. So the number of roots in the closed unit disk is finite by compactness of the closed disk,.

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy Thanks. And is Jensen's formula is valid if $f$ has zeros on the circle $|z|=R$?

Comment: @Robert Z I mean that $f$ has zeros $a_i \neq 0$ on the unit circle.

Comment: @Robert Z But I am telling that is Jensen's formula true if f has zeros in $|z|<R$ but also some zeros on $|z|=R$?

Comment: @Robert Z see- https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4054635/jensens-formula-application-fz-has-no-zeros-on-z-r-r1?r=SearchResults

Comment: @Chris OK. I was not aware of this extension.

Comment: @Robert Z Please answer this question- https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4133734/riemann-hypothesis-balazard-criterion